# How to set the http referer header with Selenium C# PhantomJSDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, phantomjs, http-referer

How can I set the http referer header when using the Selenium C# PhantomJSDriver in a C# console application?

I am using the PhantomJSDriver with a Proxy that I do not control.

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.AddArgument("--proxy=123.456.78.910:80");
service.AddArgument("--proxy-auth=myproxyuid:myproxypwd");
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.testsite.com/product/123/");
```

However the web application being tested performs validation on the [HTTP Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14) value in the requests.

**What method can I use to inject the HTTP Referer in the PhantomJSDriver requests?**

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question.

I discovered how to set / inject / fake the HTTP Referer using C# PhantomJSDriver.

It turns out adding custom headers will also set/override the standard headers.

Setting the HTTP Referer was very similar to how you set the user agent.

Use **PhantomJSOptions** to set the HTTP Referer.

Note: I used the PhantomJSDriverService as well as PhantomJSOptions to create an instance of the driver in order to send command line arguments to phantomjs.exe in order specify my proxy settings, etc.

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.AddArgument("--proxy=123.456.78.910:8181");
service.AddArgument("--load-images=false");

var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "myagent/blah.blah");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Referer", "https://www.google.com/");

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service,options)
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Great, Thanks, you did it.